# Basic SQL Sums, Selects, WHERES, GROUP BY statements

Tags: mysql, join

I'm currently working on this data.

What should be resulting:

[image]

What should be produced is the result at the bottom of that picture.

Instead, I'm getting the result:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
SELECT distinct(username) as 'Name', p.price as 'Price', p.quantity as 'Quantity', (p.price * p.quantity) as 'Total'
 FROM users u, purchase p
WHERE u.userID = p.userID 
ORDER BY (username) asc  ;
```

I am wondering how would I go about adding up the unique usernames (Alice's 4 and 1.5 to produce 5.5) and how do I also get Matt's name to display on the data?

Comment: Why is jquery tagged?

Comment: `distinct` is NOT a function, it qualifies the selection. `select distinct` affects the whole row, not just the column inside those parentheses (which are simply ignored by the way).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Just minor changes, but the important thing is to group by user and not order by user

```
SELECT username as 'Name', SUM(p.price * p.quantity) as 'Total'
 FROM users u, purchase p
WHERE u.userID = p.userID 
GROUP BY username;
```

Comment: Thank you.  The problem was just a simple confusion between ORDER BY and GROUP BY.  However, when I run the query, it doesn't display Matt's totals at all.  I also would like his totals to be displayed on it.  I imagine it's caused by setting the userID's from each table equal to each other.

Comment: Then you need to change the FROM line to `FROM users u LEFT JOIN purchase p`

Comment: I did try that before.  But, there's a syntax error with the WHERE clause.  17:07:47 SELECT DISTINCT username as 'Name', SUM(p.price * p.quantity) as 'Total' FROM (users u) LEFT JOIN (purchase p) WHERE u.userID = p.userID  GROUP BY username Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE u.userID = p.userID  GROUP BY username' at line 3 0.000 sec

Comment: I think it's because of the parentheses you added to the table names in the FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

select u.name, sum(quantity*price) as total from [User] u left join Purchase p on u.id=p.userId 
group by u.name

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've only recently started learning SQL and you have all been a very big help.  That resolved my problem.  Thank you for the input.